How to pop up a popMenu for the onLongPress of a DataRow in a dataTable
How to pop up a popMenu for the onLongPress of a DataRow in a DataTable
I want a long press of the row to bring up a pop menu at the position of the press
How does this work
Look forward to help
How to pop up a PopMenu for the onLongPress of a DataRow in a DataTable



Yes you can do that using onLongPress of the DataCell using showMenu function, It depends on you which row and which cell you want to display Popup onLongPress, like below code.
DataCell(
          onLongPress: () {
            print('Long Press');
            showMenu(
              context: context,
              position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
                  10, 150, 10, 10), // manage position on your need
              items: [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text("Copy"),
                      Icon(Icons.copy),
                    ],
                  ),
                ), 
              ],
            );
          },
          Text('Sarah'),
        ),

Full Example:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const DataTableExampleApp());

class DataTableExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DataTableExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('DataTable Sample')),
        body: const DataTableExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DataTableExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const DataTableExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: const <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Name',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Age',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Role',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      rows: <DataRow>[
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(
              onLongPress: () {
                print('Long Press');
                showMenu(
                  context: context,
                  position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
                      10, 150, 10, 10), // manage position on your need
                  items: [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text("Copy"),
                          Icon(Icons.copy),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text("Share"),
                          Icon(Icons.share),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text("Favourite"),
                          Icon(Icons.favorite),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text("Delete"),
                          Icon(Icons.delete),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
              Text('Sarah'),
            ),
            DataCell(Text('19')),
            DataCell(Text('Student')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Result Screen: 

But this position is so fixed that you can't set a RelativeRect to its current pressed position

@laterday I can't understand, Can you explain in details

RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
10, 150, 10, 10)  This position is fixed in the code, and I expect the position of the box to be where my finger is pressing

@laterday if you don't need this position then you should be use position: RelativeRect.fill instead of RelativeRect.fromLTRB( 10, 150, 10, 10) hope its help to you.

You may have misunderstood me, but I want my pop-up box to appear near where I clicked，RelativeRect.fill and RelativeRect.fromLTRB( 10, 150, 10, 10)   Are fixed positions, rather than following the mouse pointer click position

@laterday If you used RelativeRect.fill then your popup box over the where you clicked

RelativeRect.fill is always the top left corner of the screen

@laterday you can try this position as well hope its help to you.

The problem should be that there is no way to get the current click location from onLongPress
